# Can I modify the email that's created from a WI when I click the "send work item to microsoft outlook" button?

Tags: tfs-workitem

Can I modify the email that's created from a work item when I click the "send work item to microsoft outlook" button?

I've found a transform that allows you to alter the email related to an alert but (so far) not for this button? any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, with a small workaround.

Here's how: 
1. Setup a Query that includes the fields you would like to show in the email. Filter it to include the criteria of your needs.

(In my case, I've chosen Team Project, ID, Title, Assigned To, State, History, Description. )

2. Run the query. It will likely give you a list of tasks/Work Items that apply to the query.
3. Right click on the one you wish to email, and select Send Selection to MS Outlook.

**  'Viola' - it will include the fields you've selected.

[image: Simple example of TFS and resulting email]

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do that. It is on our backlog, but it will not be part of TFS vNext (TFS11)

Ewald Hofman (Program Manager TFS)